# Shell script: changing text file without knowing the original value

Tags: shell, sed, debian

the situation is the following: I'm with a VPS hoster which generates random SSH ports on installation and I have a configure.sh file which contains for example this line to change the SSH port:

```
sed -i 's/Port 22/Port 1337/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

This works great, but I need have set the currently SSH port in the sed command and obviously I don't know it when it gets generated randomly.

Regards,
Akitoyo

Comment: sample input and expexted ouptut please.

Comment: Use the `{}` edit tool at the top  left to format code and data so it is readable. Anything that clarifies the problem description should be part of the question and not a comment. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
sed -i 's/Port [0-9]*/Port 1337/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

It will change any `Port xxx` where `xxx` is any number to `Port 1337`

Comment: That will also accept zero digits after Port; I'm not sure whether that would matter, but it might be safer to use `[0-9][0-9]*` or `[0-9]\{1,\}` (the first option is actually one character shorter).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what about `sed 's/Port [^ ]*/Port 1337/'`

Comment: Thanks for your anwers, is it possible change the sed command, so that it even accepts ports with 5 digits? E.g. it just generated Port 26832

Comment: @Akitoyo Both my post supports any port from `1` to `65535`. It just replace the first group of number to a number of choice.

Comment: My (admittedly minor) concern is the `*` which allows zero or more of the previous pattern (either `[0-9]` or `[^ ]`), so if there was a comment 'the Port line needs to be edited', it would be changed too.  On the whole, this is trivia that is not critical.  In an extended RE notation (`sed -r` or `sed -E` on systems that support it), you'd replace `*` with `+`; the classic way to write `+` in `sed` is `\{1,\}` (one or more).

Comment: So you mean if there is anything with port in there this will change as well to Port 1337? Can you suggest me a correct solution for debian?:)

Comment: @Akitoyo You are saying that there may be more line with `Port` in it? And you have only one that you need to change.  Then you need a trigger on that line that is unique. If you gave example on lines that has `Port` in it, and what to change, we can help.  Also trigges based on line number, neighbor lines etc can help. Posting complete file is best.